# how to delete the first commit and make its immediate child the root

Tags: git

I have `commit-id1` from a git commit but this is the first commit so it has no parent. There is a `commit-id2` whose is its immediate child.

This is the scenario `commit-id1 ----> commit-id2 ----> commit-id3 ...`

is there a safe way to delete `commit-id1` and make `commit-id2` the first commit

i.e., `commit-id2 ----> commit-id3 ...`

I read about `git rebase -onto` but it requires a parent and not able to figure it out

Edit: The commits are pushed to the server and I would like to delete it from the server too

Comment: Have you tried `--root`?

Comment: would the command go something like `git rebase --root commit-id2` ? I had not come across this thanks for the tip

Comment: Why would you like it? The whole history of the involved branches will have to be rewritten or get diverged. It's not a good idea for published branches if many are coworking.

Comment: I am not worried about that since I never mentioned that in my question. Please let me know if the question needs edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do

```
$ git rebase -i --root
```

This starts an interactive rebase. Your text editor will open with a list of all commits that will be rebased as well as instructions. Edit the file so that the first commit is skipped. Now save the file and close your text editor.

This will remove the commit from your local history. If you need to update a remote, then you will have to force push, just like with any local history revision:

```
$ git push origin master
```

Replace `origin` with the appropriate remote name and `master` with the appropriate branch name.

Comment: will this also remove the file on the server?

Comment: @knk I assume you mean "remove the commit" (and associated content). I will update my answer to include that.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice `git push -f origin master` or `git push origin +master`.

Comment: fatal: Needed a single revision

Comment: @AlexeySh. If you encountered a problem attempting to use my solution given here, you should post a new question. Be sure to include the exact steps that you tried as well as a link back to this question.